# Is it possible changing y axis of dendrogram from height to similarity?

Tags: data-visualization, dendrogram

I made dendrogram based on species data of different sites using ward's method

Chord transformation was applied and the (dis)similarity was calculated by vegan package

Here is my question : Can I convert the height to PERCENT (similarity)

At the second plot, the similarity (y axis) is the result from conversion ratio of original plot
(I set the maximum value as 100)

But I cant be convinced whether this method is theoretically correct or not

If I want similarity as y axis of dendrogram, should I use other method?

[image]

Comment: Obviously, this depends on the definition of "similarity". What is the definition that you would like to use and how is it (if at all) related to Ward's cluster distance?

Comment: I'd say that you could use any monotonic transformation of the dendrogram scale, but some transformations are likely to be clearer to readers than others. All hinges not so much on what you use, but more on how helpful that is to others. As far as I am concerned flipping the scale so that bottom becomes top would be fine so that sign changes are allowed. It seems that the word _dendrogram_ was introduced into biological taxonomy by E. O. Wilson and collaborators in 1953, and no doubt they were following some biological convention, but that should not seem binding on anyone outside biology.

Comment: This method looks arbitrary to me: it amounts to *labeling* the top as 0% "similarity" and the bottom as 100%.  Therefore there can be no general theoretical justification for it.  That doesn't mean it's necessarily wrong; but whether calling it "similarity" and referring to it as "%" makes any sense must depend on the original clustering method and the definition of the distance employed.